# C# - end/finished "event" of a recursive function?

Tags: c#, recursion, directory

Lets assume the following function:

```
private void ParseFolder(string strFolder)
{
    foreach (string currentFolder in Directory.GetDirectories(strFolder))
    ParseFolder(strFolder);
}
```

Now we start our recursive loop with:

```
ParseFolder("C:\");
```

Is there a way to be notified when this recusrive loop ends (= all directories have been parsed)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just add a method call after it:

```
ParseFolder("C:\\"); // You need to escape \
Notify();
```

Comment: Haha. I found that funny for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void DoWork()
{
     ParseFolder("C:\\");
     // Once you get here, the work is done.
}


private void ParseFolder(string strFolder)
{
    foreach (string currentFolder in Directory.GetDirectories(strFolder))
    ParseFolder(strFolder);
}
```